# Choosing function at compile time based on argument size

Tags: c++

Is there a way to generate code (at compile time) which looks a bit like:

```
T Func(T t){
    if (sizeof(t) == 2){
        return X(t);
    }
    else if( sizeof(t) == 4){
        return Y(t);
    }
}
```

(Where T is either int32 or int16)

So at run-time i can call:

```
Func(_myInt)
```

And the code will just compile down to either `X(_myInt)` or `Y(_myInt)`.

Comment: Read up about [templates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm).

Comment: @EdHeal, no need for templates here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
X Func(int32_t t) {
    return X(t);
}

Y Func(int16_t t) {
    return Y(t);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By tag dispatching:

```
template <typename T>
auto Func_impl(T t, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2>){
   return X(t);
}

template <typename T>
auto Func_impl(T t, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 4>){
   return Y(t);
}

template <typename T>
auto Func(T t){
   return Func_impl(T, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(T)>{});
}
```

Comment: You do not even need tag dispatching here! Simple overload for int32_t and int16_t would do!

Comment: Or you could always add the X or Y in the template
`auto wVar = Func<X, int32>(123);` But that adds responsability on the caller

Comment: @KerrekSB, it's cheating. Quoting OP: `Where T is either int32 or int16` Where does unsigned int come from in your demo?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, just in case you wanted to dispatch on absolute size only, there is also enable_if:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == 2>* = nullptr>
auto Func(T t){

}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == 4>* = nullptr>
auto Func(T t){

}

int main()
{
  Func(std::uint16_t(10));
  Func(std::uint32_t(10));
}
```